# Bower restores to /wwwroot in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bower, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have an ASP.NET 4 MVC 5 project created in Visual Studio 2015 and I have a package.json file (for NPM configuration) and bower.json (for Bower configuration). By default, Bower is restoring packages under /wwwroot, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to change this behavior and specify a path for Bower package restores either in Visual Studio 2015 or in one of the configuration files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: there is a .bowerrc file created in the project folder bower.json is added to (I assume by Visual Studio 2015 when you add the bower.json file to the project) that contains the configuration for Bower, by default:

```
{
    "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

I changed the value for "directory" to a different folder and all worked as expected.